# Well is not responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I have a big problem with my page and I can't find a solution anywhere. Could anyone help me?

When I try to add a well with elements inside my page sometimes need scrolling.

There is my code. Thank you.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        <h1> Some text</h1>
        <div class="well">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="image" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
              <p class="tittle">Tittle</p>
              <p class="font"> Nullam consectetur nunc massa. Praesent arcu libero, porttitor ut lacus nec, elementum sagittis est. Donec finibus ex eget nibh blandit, a gravida justo tincidunt. Integer efficitur risus et blandit molestie. Sed hendrerit accumsan faucibus.
                Quisque urna ligula, ultrices et scelerisque sed, blandit sed ligula. Etiam odio sem, semper non ex sit amet, euismod pharetra dolor. Donec tristique quis neque vel tincidunt. Sed tincidunt, metus sed varius blandit </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For a start, you cannot nest containers. Then you can't have a `col-*` inside anything other than a `row`. Read the docs and get familiar with the rules or you will always have problems.

Comment: @DavidG comment is on-point for solving your problem.  And not to nit-pick, but you _can_ (and sometimes want to) have `.col-*` as direct descendants of elements other than `.row`, but it _is correct_ that the `.col-*` is specifically designed to be a descendant of `.row`.

Comment: @cale_b I'm not sure you're right, there's always a better way to format your layout. If it comes to it, break out of Bootstrap completely if you have to, but don't break it's rules or you leave yourself open to all manner of issues.